# Ionic/Cordova Facebook login stopped working

Tags: cordova, ionic2, firebase-authentication, cordova-plugins, angularfire2

I have been using `Ionic 3.1.1` with the `Cordova Facebook Plugin` with [`AngularFire2`](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/AngularFire2-Ionic2-Facebook) to log into `Firebase`. It has been working perfectly for months, and has now stopped working. (I am not sure if it is a result of an upgrade from `Ionic 2` to Ionic `3.1.1`)

Here is my code:

**login.ts**

```
loginFacebookCordova(): Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
    return new Promise<FirebaseAuthState>((resolve) => {
        Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
            let cred: firebase.auth.AuthCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
                resolve(data);
            });
        }, error => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.error('loginFacebook: ' + error);
            this.doAlert('loginFacebook: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
}

loginFacebookBrowser(): Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
    return new Promise<FirebaseAuthState>((resolve) => {
        this.af.auth.login({ provider: AuthProviders.Facebook, method: AuthMethods.Popup }).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
            resolve(data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.error('loginFacebook', error);
            this.doAlert('loginFacebook: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.4">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="theWhoZoo" />
</plugin>
```

**1. Browser**

If I try login with a browser (non Cordova), I get the following warning in the console:

> auth.js:101 firebase.auth.AuthCredential.provider is deprecated.
>   Please use the providerId field instead.

I then get a verification email, which I verify as usual, and then attempt to log in. It fails with the following error message:

> core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading
>   chunk 4 failed. Error: Loading chunk 4 failed.

**2. Android Devise**

When I try login with an Android device (Cordova plugin), I get the following:

> Invalid key has: The key has xXXXXXXXXXXX= does not match any stored
>   hashes. Configure your app key hashes at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXXXXXX/

When I look at the basic settings at [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com), my `APP ID` matches the variable `APP_ID` in my `config.xml`.

I am using:

```
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"firebase": "^3.7.5",
```

I have looked through documentation, and I cannot find what has changed or what may have affected this Facebook login. If anyone can assist I would greatly appreciate it.

I need help with both browser and Cordova login.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in developers.facebook.com my `Key Hash` was incorrect. This fixed the issue for the Android login as well as the browser login (not sure why?).

`developers.facebook.com -> Settings -> Basic - Android -> Key Hashes.`